# Prove that a function is not injective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help solving the next question, I think that it's actually a refutation:

> let $f,g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$  so that $\forall n ∈ \mathbb{N} : f(n) = g(2n)$
>   Prove that if $f$ is surjective $g$ is not injective

Comment: What are thoughts about it? What have you found out? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to say that:  
> let $n1,n2∈\mathbb{N}$ so that $g(n1) = g(n2)$, so $f(n1/2) = g(n1)$, but from now and on how does $f$ being surjective helps me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is sujective, then $g(1)$ is in the image of $f$. That is, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=g(1)$.

But $f(n)=g(2n)$, so you get $g(2n)=g(1)$.

Because you cannot have $2n=1$, you deduce that $g$ is not injective.

Comment: thank you very much!